# Windows Phone 8.1 get NFCTag's unique ID (RFID)

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

Is it possible to get the unique ID of an NFCTag with Windows Phone 8.1? The documentation is very confusing and i can't find any information about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There's no way of getting this.

Windows Phone doesn't expose low level enough APIs.

Comment: thanks for sharing knowlege. i can't understand why microsoft still behave like this... sitting in a cage is no fun as developer. this only keeps useful apps away from windows phone. sry for offtopic but it is really frustrating.